# folder path is denied

Tags: c#, webclient

When creating an instance of the WebClient class and when trying to download a file at the specified URL, with the specified path of the folder where you want to save the file, an error occurs: Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

```
        static public void DownloadFile()
        {
            WebClient WebClient = new WebClient();
            WebClient.DownloadFile(Config.URL, Config.ImageLink);
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide all the [exception details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: Does the target download folder actually exist?

Comment: Naming a variable with the same name as a class makes your code very hard to read. As a reader, I need to ask myself: is `WebClient.DownloadFile` a static method of the `WebClient` class or is an instance method being called through the `WebClient` variable

Answer (score 0):

Add appropiate folder permissions(write permissions) for user that created the process.

Or you can Impersonate with user account that have write permissions on the folder.

[Impersonate users in C#](https://daoudisamir.com/impersonate-users-in-c/)
[How do you do Impersonation in .NET? stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)